# Is there a simple way to access project resource files from a gradle task?

Tags: gradle

I am working on a Gradle task for a java project. The task needs to read files from a subfolder of the project’s resources directory. I was expecting to find a standard way for Gradle to access project resources but have been unable to find one.  Does Gradle provide simple way to find and import resource files? Maybe through a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the `src/main/resources` folder, then no. That is by convention used by the Java plugin to hold resources for the actual module and not the build classpath. But if you just want to read a file in it from a task, just use normal Java, Groovy or Kotlin APIs. You don't need a plugin for that.

Here is one for Groovy:

```
task printMyResource {
  doLast {
    logger.quiet(file("src/main/resources/subfolder/my_file.txt").text)
  }
}
```

(The [file](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#file-java.lang.Object-) method resolves a path to a File object relative to the project folder.)

Comment: Thank you!  This much more elegant than I imagined.